Find $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n \left( {1\over (3n-1)^3}+{1\over (3n)^3}+{1\over (3n+1)^3} \right)$
From $$\zeta(3)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over n^3}, $$ we can derive
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over (3n)^3}={1\over27}\zeta(3),$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( {1\over (3n-1)^3}+{1\over (3n+1)^3} \right) ={26\over27}\zeta(3)-1,$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(-1)^n\over (3n)^3}=-{1\over36}\zeta(3).$$
But how can we evaluate the sum of alternatings of non-$3n$ terms?
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n \left( {1\over (3n-1)^3}+{1\over (3n)^3}+{1\over (3n+1)^3} \right)$$
$$=-{1\over2^3}-{1\over3^3}-{1\over4^3}+{1\over5^3}+{1\over6^3}+{1\over7^3}-{1\over8^3}-\ldots$$

Using this, we can evaluate each sum as follows,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(3n)^3}=-\frac{6\zeta(3)}{216}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(3n+1)^3}=\frac{1}{216}\left[\zeta\left(3,\frac{7}{6}\right)-\zeta\left(3,\frac{2}{3}\right)\right]$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(3n-1)^3}=\frac{1}{216}\left[\zeta\left(3,\frac{5}{6}\right)-\zeta\left(3,\frac{1}{3}\right)\right]$$
Adding up all three we get,
$$\boxed{S=\frac{1}{216}\left[\zeta\left(3,\frac{5}{6}\right)-\zeta\left(3,\frac{1}{3}\right)+\zeta\left(3,\frac{7}{6}\right)-\zeta\left(3,\frac{2}{3}\right)-6\zeta(3)\right]}$$
$$\boxed{S=\frac{1}{216}\left(150\zeta(3)-216\right)}$$
$$\zeta(3)\approx 1.20$$
$$\zeta\left(3,\frac{7}{6}\right)\approx 0.79$$
$$\zeta\left(3,\frac{5}{6}\right)\approx 1.97$$
$$\zeta\left(3,\frac{1}{3}\right)\approx 27.56$$
$$\zeta\left(3,\frac{2}{3}\right)\approx 3.69$$
$$\boxed{S \approx -0.1652}$$
